# How to rearrange a bootstrap layout with nested divs for different screen sizes without duplicating content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I'm trying to think of a way to simplify the HTML for a webpage as much as possible.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Jade to arrange the site. It's working rather well except for this one page. Where I've had to duplicate the content four times to get the layout I desired as the ordering and/or nesting changes for each.

I know it's possible to use push/pull to reorder things, but the nesting seems to make that rather difficult.

To make matters worst, is that this creates duplicate ids, and I haven't been able to figure out how to assign and use unique IDs with Jade.

Note, I changed the includes file names to numbers for client privacy.

```
block content
  .visible-lg
    .col-sm-4
      include ./includes/index/1.jade
    .col-sm-4
      include ./includes/index/3.jade
      include ./includes/index/2.jade
    .col-sm-4
      include ./includes/index/4.jade
      include ./includes/index/5.jade

  .visible-md
    .col-md-4
      include ./includes/index/1.jade
      include ./includes/index/2.jade
    .col-md-8
      include ./includes/index/3.jade
      .col-md-6
        include ./includes/index/4.jade
      .col-md-6
        include ./includes/index/5.jade

  .visible-sm
    .col-sm-6
      include ./includes/index/1.jade
      include ./includes/index/2.jade
    .col-sm-6
      include ./includes/index/3.jade
      include ./includes/index/4.jade
      include ./includes/index/5.jade

  .visible-xs
    include ./includes/index/1.jade
    include ./includes/index/3.jade
    include ./includes/index/4.jade
    include ./includes/index/5.jade
    include ./includes/index/2.jade
```

Comment: Please post the generated output + demo.

Comment: The includes just add a heading and a paragraph of content except for #1 which is a slide show and #2 which is social media. Looking at other questions, looks like flexbox might be the only way to do it in just css.